# How to phrase "my time and Bob's time" more succinctly?

Tags: grammaticality, possessives, conjunctions

I can say "Bob and I are going" instead of "I'm going and Bob is going." I want to say something like "This is a waste of my time and Bob's time," but only saying "time" once. I can't say "our" because I'm introducing the other person's name in this sentence. The best I can think of is "This is a waste of me and Bob's time," but that seems incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like

> Bob's and my time

or (less common)

> Bob's time and mine?

Comment: "Bob's time and mine" = "My time and Bob's"?

Comment: #Bruno - I think that depends on the emphasis in speaking. I would tend to think that the emphasis would be on `mine` in `Bob's time and mine`.

Answer (score 3):

> This is a waste of my time and Bob's

Answer (score 2):

How about "This is a waste of **my and Bob's time**"?

Comment: i was thinking of that but it sounds a bit awkward..

Answer (score 0):

This is a waste of time, both for Bob and myself